# Python: alternatives to eval

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is any safe alternative to eval, that would allow me to pass class objects. The below code looks fine, but I don't want to use eval.

```
class IsCat():
    def miau(self):
        pass
    
class IsDog():
    def bark(self):
        pass
    
class IsElefant():
    def trump(self):
        pass

string = """[("5", 28, [IsCat],[IsCat, IsDog], "Elefant", [IsElefant]), ("7", 30, [IsCat],[IsCat, IsDog], "Elefant", [IsElefant])]"""
print(eval(string))
```

I have run across this `ast.literal_eval()`. However, this would fail with

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7fb8d561d3d0>.
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is it for safety-issues i.e evaluating user-code or...?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What is your primary problem that led you to this situation and to `eval`?